# Как преобразовать a/b` в сумму чисел вида `1/n`?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, теория-чисел

Задача: преобразовать `a/b` в сумму чисел вида `1/n`. Например, когда `a=3` и `b=7`, то программа должна вывести `3/7 = 1/3 + 1/11 + 1/231`.

Алгоритм я-то уже придумал, но никак не могу написать.

Сам алгоритм:

если `a>b`, то надо запомнить целое число, например, если `a=10` и `b=7`,  то надо довести до `3/7` и запомнить `1` как целое число.

Если `a < b`, то всё нормально и начинается цикл `for`. 
В нем `i = 2` и оно должно доходить до значении `b`. (После этого нет никакого смысла проверять.) Берём `b` и делим на `i`. Если значение меньше значения `a`, то `i` становится на `1` больше. И так продолжается до тех пор, пока `a > b/i`. После того как найдется первое такое число, оно запоминается (то есть запоминается `i`) для вывода на экран )(`i = 3`, то в консоль надо вывести `1/3+`. Потом выделяется это значение к начальному и начинается всё сначало, пока `а` не будет равно `1`. (Пример: было `3/7` и становится `3/7 - 1/3 = 2/21`,  `а` присваивается значение `2`, а `b` - значение `21`)

мои необыкновенный код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int a;
int b;
int c;
float d;
int k;
int g;
int e [k];  

cout << "значение а";
cin >>  a;
cout << "значение б";
cin >>  b;

if( a > b ){
    c = a / b;
    b = a - (b*c);

    return c, b;
}  else
for( int i = 2 ; i++ ; i >= b ){
    while(a>d){
        d = b / i;
    }

    int f = b;
    b = b * i;
    a = ( (b/f) * a ) - (b/i);

    e [k] = i;
    k = k+1;
}

while(e[k]>0){
    cout << "1/+" << e[k];
    k++;
}

}
```

Comment: a/b = a * 1/b = 1/b + 1/b + 1/b + ... + 1/b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, вы пытаетесь описать алгоритм Фибоначчи для египетских дробей?

Я его "на коленке" реализовал примерно как

```
void egypt(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b)
{
    if (unsigned long long g = gcd(a,b); g != 1) { a/=g; b/=g;}

    if (a > b)
    {
        cout << a/b;
        a %= b;
        if (a == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " + ";
            egypt(a,b);
        }
    }
    else if (a == 1)
    {
        cout << "1/" << b << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned long long n = (b+a)/a;
        cout << "1/" << n << " + ";
        egypt(a*n-b,b*n);
    }
}
```

Полный код - https://ideone.com/IQY14q

Но учтите, что это далеко не оптимальный алгоритм, и в плохих вариантах быстро выходит даже за рамки `unsigned long long` - как в последнем примере по указанному адресу, разложение неверное - последняя дробь в `unsigned long long` не помещается :(

Comment: Я ни так хорош в програмировании, не понимаю для чего надо этот unsigned long, я просписал только лонг и всё работает как надо :)

Comment: Далеко не всегда это будет работать как надо. Разложите 5/121 и убедитесь - выполнив суммирование карандашом на бумажке - что вы получили неверный результат... Даже размера `unsigned long long` для этого примера не хватает.

Comment: Да, цифра очень длинная и потому тупит да ? Даже лонг лонг не хватает :) Всё равно спасибо вам.

Answer (score 5):

Разложение на [египетские дроби](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8) методом Фибоначчи на Python (длинная арифметика встроенная), код не проверяет, что дробь правильная.

```py
def egy(p, q):
    res = []
    while p > 0:
        den = (q + p - 1) // p
        res.append(den)
        rem = (-q) % p
        p, q = rem, den * q
    return res
    
print(egy(3,7))
print(egy(7,15))
print(egy(5,121))
```

```
[Dbg]>>> 
[3, 11, 231]
[3, 8, 120]
[25, 757, 763309, 873960180913, 1527612795642093418846225]
```